# Multiple SSL certificates on single instance hosted on virtual machine with Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

With Using Windows azure Virtual machine,
Is that possible to install multiple SSL certificates on single instance ?

Can any one provide example/steps ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, quite possible. For IAAS it will be same as installing certificates to any other windows machine running IIS.

Assuming the VM you are referring to runs Windows OS running IIS

- Step 1: Export all your certificates to .pfx file with Passwords
- Step    2: Copy the .pfx files to the target VM remotely.
- Step 3:
  Open IIS ->    Server Certificates -> Import wizard to install the
  certificates on    the VM

Comment: The problem with Windows Azure VMs however is that you can't have multiple IP addresses pointing at them so if you're planning on using them for websites, this won't work...